# Getting "Assertion failed: Expected function name "for", was """ error on console

Tags: cucumber, angular5, chai, yarnpkg

When I am running my angular 5 application in prod mode using yarn, the browser console gives errors like

> Assertion failed: Expected function name "for", was ""

Attaching screenshot for the same.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details for the errors? (i.e. when you expand, what is the call stack shown)

Comment: The call stack is says "s @ scripts.d3acb15….bundle.js:1". The issue comes only when the prod build is run.

Comment: So far what I could find is there is a library which we are using, whose minified reference is present in .angular-cli.json. When I change this reference from minified to unminified version, the errors don't come.